# Open Safari from a link without using openURL

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I actually have an app on the App Store.

It contains some UIWebView calling pages on my server.

The problem is that I'd like to add a link on one of those pages, which will open Safari . But I don't want to do a version update to add :

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];`

I've been using custom url scheme, and I wonder if there is a way to open Safari with such a hint. I don't find any answer on the web, so maybe it's just impossible...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do this using the data: scheme and using page content that does a location change.

http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/apple-safari-data

Like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      document.location='http://www.google.com';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which is

encoded to this:

data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+DQo8Ym9keT4NCjxzY3JpcHQgbGFuZ3VhZ2U9IkphdmFTY3JpcHQiPg0KZG9jdW1lbnQubG9jYXRpb249J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSc7DQo8L3NjcmlwdD4NCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=